# Cosmos db SQL API maximum query limit

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using cosmos db , sql api. I want to know what is the maximum character limit for queries.

Below post mentions > 30 kb for Mongo API :
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/32665819-increase-query-maximum-character-limit-for-cosmo-m

Is there a similar limit for SQL API as well ?

Thanks !

EDIT 1 :  I am testing this on the cosmos db emulator on my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max query size is 256 KB. You can find this and other service quota and limits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#sql-query-limits).

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but how do i calculate it for my query ? I am doing a findByVariableIn() in my Java's JPA repository and passing a list of 3000 Strings of 4 characters each , which by  UTF-8 encoding becomes 4 bytes each, so totals to 3000x4 = 12 kb.  I get a "gone exception" in this case. It works fine if im passing only 2000 strings. I am using cosmos DB emulator .

Comment: The linked page states the current limit to be 512KB